# Calculating the frequency of a sinewave with the cutoff frequency, the input and output amplitudes of the sinewave?

Tags: filter, passive-filter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBPlmU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know there's a question similar to this on the website but that wasn't solved as not enough details were given.

It is a first order, low pass filter.

I have a corner frequency of 3000Hz, an input sinewave of amplitude 12.00V and output sinewave of amplitude 0.012V. I'm unsure as to how to work out the frequency of the sinewave.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of filter - high-pass or low-pass? What order of filter? What filter topology? There's nowhere near enough info in your question to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Dividing the input and output values gives you the attenuation as a decimal, which can be converted to dB.  After that, it's what brhans said - no information about the circuit = no answer.

Comment: Sorry I should've specified. It is a first order low pass filter @brhans

Comment: Figure out how much first order filter attenuates, and you have all the info you need to draw a bode plot.

Comment: Most of us here know how to solve this. But, you will learn more if you make an effort yourself:  Draw a bode plot. What is the ratio of output to input?  What is it in decibels?

Answer (score 1):

Find the attenuation factor for your filter at the given frequency, which is usually expressed in dB. Then use this equation:

\$ dB = 20 \log\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$

If you need to know what the dB attenuation factor is for your filter, use [this guide](https://www.sensorsmag.com/components/introduction-to-analog-filters)

To find the frequency of a low pass filter, you use this equation

\$  \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{1}{2\pi R C}\$

Comment: So the 20log(Vout/Vin) gives the answer of -60. Where do I go from here? I've read the guide you linked although I'm still feeling a little lost after getting to this value. I'm new to electronics so please forgive my lack of understanding :)

Comment: You should know what the voltage in to the filter is, why don't you post the filter, you can draw the filter with the tool edit your question

Comment: I have drawn it and added it to the question. The information located in the drawing/question is all of the information I have regarding the problem

Comment: What is the frequency of your sine wave

Comment: That is what i'm trying to figure out

Comment: Your source is determined by the voltage going in, What is your voltage source? Is it a sine wave? DC? from a sensor what is it?

Comment: The input into the filter is a sinewave, as stated in the question

Comment: At what frequency? Sine waves have a specific frequency, you mentioned a corner frequency, corner frequencies can only be related to at filter, not a sine wave

Comment: In this question, a single-pole (first-order) low-pass RC filter has been designed to provide unity gain up to its corner frequency of 3000 Hz.

Suppose a sinewave of 12V amplitude is applied to the input of the filter.

A resulting sinewave of 0.012 Volts amplitude is observed at the output.

What is the approximate frequency (jn Hz) of the sinewave to 1 significant figure?
<< This is the entire question and all of the information that I have

Comment: edited the question

Comment: I found that equation when browsing a while ago, but the values of R and C are unknown so I'm not sure that it's of use to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: You can't find the values of R and C seperately, but if you know the cutoff frequency you know both of them *comblined*

Comment: and thats all you need to know

Comment: OK, -60dB at the output, good. Next, what is the attenuation per decade of a first order filter?

Comment: -20dB per decade, right?

Comment: Yes, -20dB per decade

Comment: OK, then how many decades is -60dB?

Comment: 3 decades, so the attenuation factor is 3?

Comment: @laptop2d I followed the things which you told me, but the bottom equation on the answer doesn't give me the frequency does it? From that I can just get the value of RC combined. Or is that then used in a further equation which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, 3 decades, so your input frequency to get this attenuation is 3 decades past the corner frequency. The answer would be really obvious if you made a bode plot.

Comment: Ahh okay, I've not had any experience with bode plots yet. Is there a tool to make them online do you know? Also I've done some reading up on them but struggling to understand them a little

Comment: Here is an example bode plot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot#/media/File:Bode_Low-Pass.PNG There are all kinds of tools available, but I don't know of any that would directly help you with this problem. They usually simulate using component values, or transfer functions. You could reverse engineer values or a transfer function, but that is an unnecessary step given your specific problem.

Comment: Would the answer be 1000Hz?

Comment: No. A decade is a factor of 10, so one decade past the corner freq (3kHz) would be 30kHz. Two decades past the corner freq would be ...

Comment: My bad, I read one of your previous comments wrong! So second decade past 3kHz would be 300kHz... so 3000kHz aka 3GHz would be the third decade? Or 3,000,000Hz as the question specifies the answer in Hz?

Comment: Yes, except 3,000,000 Hz is 3 MHz, not GHz.

Comment: Yeah my bad! I corrected it but due to bad connection it wouldn't update lol. Thankyou very much with your help! I appreciate it so much. Will hope to give back to this forum in the future once I am a qualified engineer. :D

Comment: @Craig https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the bode plot. Note that Bode (the man) specified straight line approximations. The value at the corner frequency is actually -3 dB below the straight line approximation. Over the years, a bode plot has come to mean the approximation or the exact curve.

I learned to solve these types of problems with graph paper. You can find printable semi-log paper here:  https://www.printablepaper.net/category/log

[image]

Comment: Note that after much discussion, the OP solved the problem, see comments in laptop2d's answer. This plot was added afterward.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple voltage divider. The voltage over the capacitor is

$$V_c =V_0 \cdot \frac{1/j \omega C_1}{R_1+1/j \omega C_1 } = \frac{1}{1+ j \omega R_1 C_1 }$$

The cutoff frequency is given by the point were voltage is dropped in half, which corresponds to 
$$ \omega_{c} R_1 C_1 = 1, -> R_1 C_1 =1/\omega_{c}  $$

We also see that |Vc| = |V0|/1000, so we get

$$ |V_0|/|V_C| = 1000 = |1 +j \omega R_1 C_1| $$

That's most easily solved looking at the square of the magnitude

$$1 + (\omega R_1 C_1)^2 = 10^6$$
$$ \omega = \frac{ \sqrt{10^6-1} }{R_1 C_1} = \sqrt{10^6-1} \cdot \omega_{c} $$

In other words, the frequency at which the voltage of the capacitor is 1000 times lower than the input voltage is roughly 1000 times the cutoff frequency or about 3 MHz.